# F#: Reduce this function

Tags: f#, lint

Consider the following piece of code:

```
scores |> Map.fold (fun state key value ->
                    state + (findCoefficient conversion.Coefficients key) * value) 
                   0m
```

`findCoefficient` returns a decimal, and `scores` is a `Map<string, decimal>`

Now when I write this piece of code in Visual Studio, the F# Power Tools give me this lint suggestion/warning:

> **Lint**: If no mutable arguments are partially applied in the chain of function calls, then the function calls and lambda could be replace with composition. e.g. `fun -> x |> isValid |> not` could be replaced with `isValid >> not`

How would I do this in this case?

Comment: Not sure the warning applies here

Comment: Is there any wider context of this code? Maybe that tip is about scores |> usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a *terrible* advice from the linter, but it follows a valid reasoning.

I replace `conversion.Coefficient` in your original snippet to make it a bit shorter:

```
scores |> Map.fold (fun state key value ->
  state + (findCoefficient coeff key) * value) 0m
```

When you have a binary operator in F# such as `a + b`, this can be rewritten as a function application `(+) a b` - and so we can rewrite the above code as:

```
scores |> Map.fold (fun state key value ->
  (+) state ((*) (findCoefficient coeff key) value)) 0m
```

Now, this is just a nested function application and so we can rewrite it with `|>`:

```
scores |> Map.fold (fun state key value ->
  value |> (*) (findCoefficient coeff key) |> (+) state) 0m
```

And now you can do what the linter suggests, which is to turn it into a function composition:

```
scores |> Map.fold (fun state key ->
  (*) (findCoefficient coeff key) >> (+) state) 0m
```

This is not something I would *ever* want to write in practice, but you can see how the rules that the linter follows in other (reasonable) cases apply here. But I'd recommend opening an issue with the [F# PowerTools](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools) suggesting that the linter should not give silly advice when the function involves binary operators :-).

Comment: Would it be better to report it directly at  [FSHarpLint](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint) ?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not sure! But either way, it'll reach the authors.